# SSRS chart grouping

Tags: sql, reporting-services

My company makes various products that go through specific manufacturing steps.

I have an SSRS report that graphs the following per step: quantity today as a bar, and then markers of quantity yesterday, the goal for the day, how many items moved in to the step today and how many moved out.

In the chart data area, I have a *category group* of step and a sum of *values* of all of the numbers. I don't have anything in the series group area. (I'm using VS 2013, also.)

The users would like to add a grouping to quantity today -- a stacked bar by product by step, but still keep the rest the same (the quantity yesterday, goal, in and out would still be by step only).

I am not sure how or if I can group on something for one value, but not for the other values.

I've tried using the series groups, or adding another category group, but nothing is quite right.

Thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added two more fields to the dataset, in addition to quantity today -- quantity special and a calculated field of quantity today minus quantity special (the remainder).

I then modified the SSRS report to NOT chart quantity today, but chart quantity special and the remainder (in the values area). I changed these both to a stacked bar.

When there is no special data, quantity today- quantity special = the original. When there is, special + remainder = the total.